# Session timeout on multiple tabs

Tags: session-timeout, spring-security

I am using Spring acegi security for single sign on on multiple applications. I need to extend session timeout at client side if user writing something on browser too. If user opended multiple sessions or browsers then i need to consider active session on all the sessions he opened. If he is active then i should not log off him eventhough he is inactive in another sessions.
Please suggest me any ideas how to track and know at the client side too.

### Any idea is greatly appreaciated. Thank you.

Running application `app1` in two tabs say `tab1` and `tab2`.Timeout is 10 minutes. So we implemented timeout functionalit in java script which is at client side. This code gives Confirm box after 10 min.  If user says continue, we are extending the session by firing the alive url. This working if application running in a single tab. Same applciation `app1` open in multiple tabs say `tab1`,`tab2`. Here applicaiton app1 opened in two tabs but single session. We are woking the application which is opened in  `tab2` and not using applciation in `tab1`. So application in tab1 is inactive for 10 min.then application in `tab1` giving confirm box and we dont answer to that confirm box tab2 will make applciation to  log out. So what is the solution for not making logout as we are working application on Tab2. Any ideas? How to track whether application in active in other tabs?

Comment: This is similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363833/how-can-you-display-a-session-timeout-warning-that-is-smart-enough-to-handle-mult)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified code in javascript to fire ajax request to server and finding the latest activity.
If latest activity is less than 10 mins then there is no logout.

Answer (score 1):

This is not straigt forword answer. (Since I do not think there is a solution for that)

you could try to fire a pixel(*) between the application and by that extends the session time.
lets say that you have:
app1, app2, app3

the user logged in to app1 and app2 and he is working only on app1.  if you fire a pixel   from his browser to app2 every http request he made on app1, he suppose to be alive on app 2 as well.
I think that if you fire the pixel every 2 minutes between the applications app1,2 and 3 you can save the session alive between the apps.

I have done this twick in PHP application, it wans'nt so easy, but it is doable.

***pixel** - *it is a hidden http request that runs a script in the serverside. can do it via ajax, img, script src="", iframe and more.*

Comment: if application say app1 is in different tabs, how we know it is active in another at client side and make session active

Comment: I have just looked into my php code, I call an empty PHP function with the pixel. the session is automatically extended. this is the default session behavior in most technologies, once you have logged in, your session will be up and running as long as you are active (making http requests). so by firing a muted pixel, you are making http requests. so the session will be active. so you have to build a JS code (same in each app) that fire the pixel every few minutes (cross app), and put a java method (in each app) that accept the pixel and return an empty string (for the http status code 200)

Comment: Please reedit your edit, I read it five time and did not understand you (BTW, in this forum "Enter" won't break a line, "enter + double space" will break)

Comment: I modified code. Sorry for confusion. I am answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to store a lastActivity timestamp in localStorage

1. User activity in any tab updates the lastActivity timestamp
2. Whenever the timer expires in any tab it should check the lastActivity value before prompting the user. If lastActivity is older than timeout, prompt the user. If not, adjust the remaining time to show prompt

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to associate the sign-in session with a shared domain. Say you have app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com, app3.domain.com, BUT you have the SSO take place on domain.com, and they all share that session cookie. This is just a matter of setting the domain on the session cookie-- I believe you can do this in the configuration. Anyway, this  pretty easy to do, so if this works with your problem, go for it. (Maybe there's some tricky way to do this without that domain hierarchy, but I'm not sure what it is.)

If that isn't workable, you may need a different way to store sessions. My first thought would be to put the sessions in the database. With these, you can synchronize and centrally manage the timeouts. This may require a little bit of custom code-- but it shouldn't be that much.

Not sure this is applicable, but I wrote my thoughts on [implementing timeout on the client side as well](http://blog.ndpsoftware.com/2011/03/friendlier-session-timeouts-20.html).